# How to design RNN\VAE for sparse sequential data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, autoencoders, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently struggling with designing some **Deep Learning algorithms** that takes as an input sparse sequential data, since the system I try to model signals **sparsely** (once in a while). 
I try to predict the next signal (strength, timing, etc).
Can you suggest an *architecture\design\method\resources* for this type of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this paper? A Recurrent Latent Variable Model for Sequential Data (https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02216)

For the sparsity, a few works I have known use time index as an additional input to the RNN (such as Recurrent Recommenders Networks (http://alexbeutel.com/papers/rrn_wsdm2017.pdf)).

Not sure if these suggestions will work for you, but at least you can try.